# UserPrincipal - filter by multi values on a property

Tags: c#, active-directory, userprincipal

I need to get all the users where the employeeType != G, J and L
All the examples I see for query-by-example are for a *single value*..
    UserPrincipal qbeUser = new UserPrincipal(ctx);
    qbeUser.Name = "Bruce";
    PrincipalSearcher srch = new PrincipalSearcher(qbeUser);
    ... Blah

How would I do this.. Notice this is a NOT equal to and it is several values for a single property..

Thanks in advance.